# cleaning txt file in R

Tags: regex, r

I found the following script from asdfree on taxonomies. The current script merges all specialties into a single column [asdfree original script](https://github.com/ajdamico/asdfree/blob/master/National%20Plan%20and%20Provider%20Enumeration%20System/merge%20taxonomy%20ids.R). The issue is that the current script ignores the hierarchy of the specialties.

The following code gives you an idea of how there are really multiple levels

```
library(downloader)
tf <- tempfile()
download("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ajdamico/asdfree/master/National%20Plan%20and%20Provider%20Enumeration%20System/taxonomy%20id%20table.txt", tf)
z <- readLines(tf)
hmt <- gregexpr("\t", z)
l <- unlist(lapply(hmt, function(x) length(x[x > 0])))

specialty_groups <- pre[l == 1]
specialty_individual <- pre[l == 2]
```

The issue is that Allegery and Immunology (in first row) is misplaced, and it should really go to the last column.

```
6      2                Allergy & Immunology  207K00000X Allopathic & Osteopathic Physicians                 <NA>
7      3                             Allergy  207KA0200X Allopathic & Osteopathic Physicians Allergy & Immunology
8      3    Clinical & Laboratory Immunology  207KI0005X Allopathic & Osteopathic Physicians Allergy & Immunology
9      2                      Anesthesiology  207L00000X Allopathic & Osteopathic Physicians                 <NA>
```

In other words, the data should really look something like this

```
LEVEL_1                              LEVEL_2              LEVEL_3                            TAXONOMY
Allopathic & Osteopathic Physicians  Allergy & Immunology                                    207K00000X
Allopathic & Osteopathic Physicians  Allergy & Immunology Allergy                            207KA0200X
Allopathic & Osteopathic Physicians  Allergy & Immunology Clinical & Laboratory Immunology   207KI0005X
```

How can I achieve this with regex in R?

Comment: Dont understand what you're trying to achieve.  What package is the `pre` function from?

Comment: `pre` is undefined here.